# PHP if variable starts with

Tags: php

I am using PHP and MySQL to submit an order to a database. When the form submits to `addorder.php` it knows to grab the `date` and `ordernumber` using post, however when it does that, I need it to perform an IF function where if `$ordernumber` starts with `7` the value of `$system = E` or if it starts with `9` the value of the `$system = O` (that is an "oh" not a zero).

I am unsure how to do this in PHP. It needs to only check the first digit in the `$ordernumber` string to verify which criteria it meets.

Comment: `if($ordernumber[0] == 7 && $system == 'E')`? Show some effort here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`strval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php) to treat a variable as a string, and then just use `[0]` to check the first digit:

```
$ch = strval($ordernumber)[0];
if ($ch == '7') {
    $system = 'E';
} elseif ($ch == '9') {
    $system = 'O';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer by Mureinik but if you don't want to change the data-type of your variable and if $ordernumber has fixed number of digits (n) you can find the first number by dividing it by 10^(n-1).
eg: if $number is 4 digit number then

```
$firstdigit=$ordernumber/1000;
```

And your code becomes

```
$firstdigit=$ordernumber/1000;
if ($firstdigit== '7') {
    $system = 'E';
} elseif ($firstdigit== '9') {
    $system = 'O';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(substr($ordernumber, 0, 1) == '7'){$system = 'E';}
if(substr($ordernumber, 0, 1) == '9'){$system = 'O';}
```